# Agora iOS AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension crash

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

I recently updated my iOS agora library version from 3.5.0.3 to 3.6.1.2, the update causing crash when I try to make a video call :

```
AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension`___lldb_unnamed_symbol1714$$AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension:
    0x10bcb04a4 <+0>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-0x20]!
    0x10bcb04a8 <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
    0x10bcb04ac <+8>:  add    x29, sp, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x10bcb04b0 <+12>: mov    x19, x0
->  0x10bcb04b4 <+16>: ldr    x0, [x1, #0x18]
    0x10bcb04b8 <+20>: cbz    x0, 0x10bcb04d8           ; <+52>
    0x10bcb04bc <+24>: cmp    x1, x0
    0x10bcb04c0 <+28>: b.eq   0x10bcb04e0               ; <+60>
    0x10bcb04c4 <+32>: ldr    x8, [x0]
    0x10bcb04c8 <+36>: ldr    x8, [x8, #0x10]
    0x10bcb04cc <+40>: blr    x8
    0x10bcb04d0 <+44>: str    x0, [x19, #0x18]
    0x10bcb04d4 <+48>: b      0x10bcb04f4               ; <+80>
    0x10bcb04d8 <+52>: str    xzr, [x19, #0x18]
    0x10bcb04dc <+56>: b      0x10bcb04f4               ; <+80>
    0x10bcb04e0 <+60>: str    x19, [x19, #0x18]
    0x10bcb04e4 <+64>: ldr    x0, [x1, #0x18]
    0x10bcb04e8 <+68>: bl     0x10bcb08e4               ; ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1756$$AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension
    0x10bcb04ec <+72>: mov    x1, x19
    0x10bcb04f0 <+76>: blr    x8
    0x10bcb04f4 <+80>: mov    x0, x19
    0x10bcb04f8 <+84>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
    0x10bcb04fc <+88>: b      0x10bcb078c               ; ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1727$$AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension
```

From crashlytics

```
Crashed: ahpl_main
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000018
Crashed: ahpl_main
0  AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension    0xd04b4 (Missing UUID 0d74db679cd5335da8a2d3eeaeedc52c)
1  AgoraVideoSegmentationExtension    0xcf8d0 (Missing UUID 0d74db679cd5335da8a2d3eeaeedc52c)
2  AgoraRtcKit                        0x548488 createAgoraRtcEngine + 2882872
3  AgoraRtcKit                        0x5483d0 createAgoraRtcEngine + 2882688
4  AgoraRtcKit                        0x544370 createAgoraRtcEngine + 2866208
5  AgoraRtcKit                        0x4da090 createAgoraRtcEngine + 2431296
6  AgoraRtcKit                        0x49a004 createAgoraRtcEngine + 2169012
7  AgoraRtcKit                        0x242f28 (Missing UUID 45ecb45d63fc310fbc18532d12bb2a9d)
8  AgoraRtcKit                        0x23fad4 (Missing UUID 45ecb45d63fc310fbc18532d12bb2a9d)
9  AgoraRtcKit                        0x23ec1c (Missing UUID 45ecb45d63fc310fbc18532d12bb2a9d)
10 AgoraRtcKit                        0x34d954 createAgoraRtcEngine + 807428
11 AgoraRtcKit                        0x34cf90 createAgoraRtcEngine + 804928
12 AgoraRtcKit                        0x34cab0 createAgoraRtcEngine + 803680
13 AgoraRtcKit                        0x28a524 createAgoraRtcEngine + 7636
14 AgoraRtcKit                        0x2505e4 (Missing UUID 45ecb45d63fc310fbc18532d12bb2a9d)
15 AgoraRtcKit                        0x25056c (Missing UUID 45ecb45d63fc310fbc18532d12bb2a9d)
16 AgoraCore                          0x140cc ahpl_queue_clear + 424
17 AgoraCore                          0x14358 ahpl_queue_run_func_arg + 576
18 AgoraCore                          0xb53c ahpl_perf_set_callback + 1468
19 AgoraCore                          0xcad0 ahpl_mpq_itc_ack + 252
20 AgoraCore                          0xc70c ahpl_mpq_loop + 76
21 AgoraCore                          0xb86c ahpl_perf_set_callback + 2284
22 AgoraCore                          0x15cf0 ahpl_profile_clear_registered + 1092
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x19a4 _pthread_start + 148
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib            0xea0 thread_start + 8
```

I didn't change anything else so I'm positive this crash caused by the update.

This crash did not occur if I have this line of code commented :

```
mRtcEngine!.enableVideo()
```

Any thoughts really appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out cocoa pod bugged out, it never update the actual used sdk, idk why

Removed the pod and reinstall from swift package manager solves it for me